# Spring app throwing java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection

Tags: spring

Long running Stand-alone Spring app on a weekly schedule (not on any App server) usually takes few days to complete but failed due to java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe.

Here's stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Broken pipe
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:876)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1153)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1275)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3576)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3620)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1491)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:93)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:703)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:644)
    ... 28 more

Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
    at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.send(DataPacket.java:199)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetOutputStream.flush(NetOutputStream.java:211)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:227)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:175)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:100)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:85)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:123)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:79)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1122)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1099)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:288)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:863)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe` exception suggests that, you are writing while the other end has already closed the connection. As the other end isn't reading it. As I also said, if this is happening there is something wrong with your application protocol specification or implementation, most probably that you don't even have one.

If application is dealing with heavy amount of data, think about JVM memory issues. Another possibility is that other end of connection does not wait long enough then it closes the connection, because application is taking too long to prepare the data and send. And connection times out.

Read [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/738b7897-cd38-4f24-9f05-48dd69116837/entry/understanding_some_common_socketexceptions_in_java3?lang=en) article to know more about it.